# Get Height of the single tableviewcell when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to get the height of the single tableveiewcell when it is tapped. I am looking around but no solution.

Any Suggestions ??

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delegate method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

Then inside that method get the cell with:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Then you should be able to get the height as a property on the cell's frame.

```
let height = cell.frame.height
```

Comment: Thanks JustJasper for the valuable information. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
 print(cell?.frame.height)

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil for the valuable information. it also worked. Your answer is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delegate Method

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

to find which cell is tapped

then with **indexPath** get Cell height

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use TableViewDelegates

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   print(cell?.frame.height)
}
```

When you select row then this method called

```
 let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

-> cell contain tapped cell info like(height,width,content..etc)
-> you use cell info where you want like you need height so you write

```
  cell?.frame.height
```

same if you want width of current cell you can write

```
  cell?.frame.width
```

If its helpfull for you ,

Thanks